# How to disable Cancel button in the installer dialog

Tags: c#, installation, custom-action

Sometimes i want disable a cancel button when installing my package, I am using visual studio installer.
[image]

I want to disable this cancel button from code side.

Comment: I don't think is possible with shipped msi installer. Maybe using more advanced stuff like InstallShield.. However, I can't think of a situation where I want to take away the freedom of my users to cancel installation whenever they want..

Comment: Try to run a custom action during the install process. Maybe you can disable the button with the Win32 API.

Comment: @Oscar -> in custom action I am calling different exe, when the exe is running user no need to cancel this installation... this is the case.

Comment: @cansik -> thanks, I tired to search some how to give API for this case, but i dint get, tell how to call..

Comment: @VikramBose > I've added an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the WIN32 API:

- Get the class name of the Window with Spy++ and search it with the function FindWindow
- Get the Button hwnd by FindWindowEx
- Disable it by EnableWindow

Here is my example code:

Win32 Function declaration:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool bEnable);
```

Code to disable the button:

```
IntPtr hwndWindow = FindWindow("MsiDialogCloseClass", "Installer");
IntPtr hwndButton = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwndWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Cancel");

if (EnableWindow(hwndButton, false))
{
    //has been disabled
}
```

Here my test window:

[image]

Comment: I tried but it's not disabled, EnableWindow(hwndButton, false) returns false, I dont know what's wrong.

Comment: IntPtr hwndWindow = FindWindow("MsiDialogCloseClass", "Installer"); the second parameter is a Caption or what?

Comment: @VikramBose The second parameter is the name of the window!